# Is 'oblige' the right word: 'thinking ... oblige us to avoid self-serving bias...'?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

> [[Para 4:]](http://www.bloombergview.com/articles/2014-01-03/the-pope-is-right-inequality-is-unjust) Rawls argued that citizens would willingly embrace this principle if they reasoned behind a “veil of ignorance” -- without knowledge of their age, race, gender, intelligence and so on. In this “original position,” citizens would care most about the interests of the least advantaged, because any citizen might turn out to be among them. Such reasoning may seem artificial, but Rawls asks us to reflect on what we mean by a just society. A just society is a fair society, he argued, and thinking about fairness **[obliges](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/oblige)** us to avoid **self-serving bias** by abstracting from all the specific things we know about ourselves.

I guess that Definition 1(.0) applies (= Make (someone) legally or morally bound to do something:), but is this use of **oblige** perfectly right? How cacn mere `thinking about fairness' to bound or affect in any way [self-serving](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/self-serving) bias (ie: bias that only advances yourself)?  What law or morality does the [author](http://www.hks.harvard.edu/about/faculty-staff-directory/christopher-robichaud) imply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text is talking about Rawls and what he argues.

> A just society is a fair society, *he argued*, and thinking about fairness obliges us to avoid self-serving bias by abstracting from all the specific things we know about ourselves.

The "he argued" in this sentence links back to a context established earlier - we're still talking about Rawls and his arguments.  Especially since a couple of sentences up, the text says:

> Rawls argued that citizens would willingly embrace this principle if they reasoned behind a “veil of ignorance” -- without knowledge of their age, race, gender, intelligence and so on.

Rawls is saying that thinking about fairness makes someone morally bound to avoid self-serving bias.  So Rawls used the right word according to how he thought of things.